# Palindrome Check in Java using two Methods will not compile

Tags: java, methods, compilation, palindrome

I was working on this for a class assignment, and I cannot for the life of me get it to compile.  I keep getting this error:

> CPT236PalindromeCheckMethod.java:52: error: reached end of file while parsing
>   } ^
>   1 error

I have tried adding, removing, and checking all of my braces, but I cannot find anything wrong with it.  I am new to programming, so I figured fresh eyes might help me find the issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CPT236PalindromeCheckMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String s = input.nextLine();

        if (checkPalindrome(s))
            System.out.println(s + " is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println(s + " is not a palindrome");
    }

    public static boolean checkPalindrome(String str){

        String lowerString = str.toLowerCase();
        String resultString = "";

        for(int i=0; i<lowerString.length(); i++) {
            if(Character.isLetter(lowerString.charAt(i))) {
            resultString = resultString + lowerString.charAt(i);
       }
    }

    int low = 0;

    int high = resultString.length() - 1;

    boolean isPalindrome = true;
    while (low < high) {
        if (resultString.charAt(low) != resultString.charAt(high)) {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
    }

    low++;
    high--; 
  }
```

}

Comment: why you dont use an `IDE`? or at least `sublime text` or `notepad++` this errors will disappear

Comment: what @SotiriosDelimanolis said. Proper indentation will do *wonders* for fixing this type of issue as it makes it very easy to spot where braces are missing.

Comment: you need to return isPalindrome in the last method.

Comment: I'm using jGrasp, an IDE that my instructor recommended.  I will take better care to properly indent my code.  Thank you all for your help, I added in the return isPalindrome and the code now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a return value in the second method. It needs to return true or false. Return isPalindrome.

You should ideally use SublimeText or Eclipse. That way it'll debug your text realtime with JAVAC, and tell you where your errors are. It's much easier to troubleshoot realtime.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CPT236PalindromeCheckMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String s = input.nextLine();

        if (checkPalindrome(s))
            System.out.println(s + " is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println(s + " is not a palindrome");
    }

    public static boolean checkPalindrome(String str) {

        String lowerString = str.toLowerCase();
        String resultString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < lowerString.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(lowerString.charAt(i))) {
                resultString = resultString + lowerString.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        int low = 0;

        int high = resultString.length() - 1;

        boolean isPalindrome = true;
        while (low < high) {
            if (resultString.charAt(low) != resultString.charAt(high)) {
                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }

            low++;
            high--;

        }
        return isPalindrome;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use IDE (like [Eclipse](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQjBAwAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.eclipse.org%2Fdownloads%2F%3FosType%3Dwin32&ei=ZZaBVZKSNYT88QXxoIHgDw&usg=AFQjCNG9LMaJ-fotUXi771x3Xjqcs1S8wQ&sig2=zjY5OPfzzCOHRR2XqNMlyQ&bvm=bv.96041959,d.dGc&cad=rja), [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)...), so that you can easily indent your code.

Now put a `}` at the end of your file.

In method `checkPalindrome()` add `return` statement.

At the end of the `while` loop,

```
while (low < high) {
    if (resultString.charAt(low) != resultString.charAt(high)) {
        isPalindrome = false;
        break;
    }

    low++;
    high--;
}
return isPalindrome; // add this line
```

I added a `return` statement,

```
return isPalindrome;
```

and run your code, with

> Input : Enter a string: madam
>
> Outout : madam is a palindrome